# error when trying to inject poller advice

Tags: spring-integration

I have implemented a polling stratergy on s3 some thing like this.I am making a webservice call to check whether i can poll file from s3 if my webservice is up then i am pulling the file

```
 import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipStrategy;
    import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperation;
    import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


    @ManagedResource
    public class ServiceHealthCheckPollSkipStrategy  implements PollSkipStrategy  {


        private volatile boolean skip;

        @Override
        public boolean skipPoll() {

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(new String("bar"));
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.
                      exchange("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/ca/mock/post", HttpMethod.OPTIONS, request, String.class);
            //Set<HttpMethod> result = restTemplate.optionsForAllow("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/ca/mock/post");


           if (response.getStatusCode().toString().equals("200")){
               this.skip = true;
           }
            return this.skip;
        }

        /**
         * Skip future polls.
         */
        @ManagedOperation
        public void skipPolls() {
            this.skip = true;
        }


        /**
         * Resume polling at the next {@code Trigger} event.
         */
        @ManagedOperation
        public void reset() {
            this.skip = false;
        }
    }
```

My application context file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-aws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws"
       xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/aws/spring-integration-aws-1.0.xsd">

   <int:poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" default="true">

    <int:advice-chain>
        <ref bean="pollAdvise"/>

        </int:advice-chain>
</int:poller>


<bean id="pollAdvise" class="org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollSkipAdvice">
    <property name="pollSkipStrategy" ref="pollerStratergy"/>


</bean>

<bean id="pollerStratergy"
            class="test.main.ServiceHealthCheckPollSkipStrategy" />
    <bean id="credentials" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.core.BasicAWSCredentials">
        <property name="accessKey" value="${accessKey}"/>
        <property name="secretKey" value="${secretKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
        <property name="proxyHost" value="${proxyHost}"/>
        <property name="proxyPort" value="${proxyPort}"/>
    <property name="preemptiveBasicProxyAuth" value="false"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="s3Operations" class="org.springframework.integration.aws.s3.core.CustomC1AmazonS3Operations">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentials"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="clientConfiguration"/>
        <property name="awsEndpoint" value="s3.amazonaws.com"/>
        <property name="temporaryDirectory" value="${temporaryDirectory}"/>
        <property name="awsSecurityKey"  value="${awsSecurityKey}"/>
    </bean>



    <!-- aws-endpoint="https://s3.amazonaws.com"  -->
    <int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter aws-endpoint="s3.amazonaws.com"
                                        bucket="${bucket}"
                                        s3-operations="s3Operations"
                                        credentials-ref="credentials"
                                        file-name-wildcard="${fileNameWildcard}"
                                        remote-directory="${remoteDirectory}"
                                        channel="splitChannel"
                                        local-directory="${localDirectory}"
                                        accept-sub-folders="false"
                                        delete-source-files="true"
                                        archive-bucket="${archiveBucket}"
                                        archive-directory="${archiveDirectory}">
    </int-aws:s3-inbound-channel-adapter>




    <int-file:splitter input-channel="splitChannel" output-channel="output" markers="false ">


    </int-file:splitter>


    <int:channel id="output"/>


</beans>
```

But when i run this i get below exception

```
2015-12-28T15:37:09-0600 1.2.1.RELEASE ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate 'IntegrationConfigurationInitializer': org.springframework.integration.http.config.HttpIntegrationConfigurationInitializer
    at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:177) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213) [spring-xd-module-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.integration.http.config.HttpIntegrationConfigurationInitializer is not assignable to interface org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConfigurationInitializer
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:369) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:352) ~[spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:46) ~[spring-integration-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
2015-12-28T15:37:09-0600 1.2.1.RELEASE WARN DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2b7b565b: startup date [Mon Dec 28 15:37:09 CST 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7d5a0b14
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213) [spring-xd-module-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
2015-12-28T15:37:09-0600 1.2.1.RELEASE WARN DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2b7b565b: startup date [Mon Dec 28 15:37:09 CST 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7d5a0b14
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836) [spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213) [spring-xd-module-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:1.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I guess by the `response.getStatusCode().toString().equals("200")` `true` result you should not `skip` the current poll, but really allow to pick up the file from the S3 source. So, revise your logic there, please.

Regarding

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.integration.http.config.HttpIntegrationConfigurationInitializer is not assignable to interface org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationConfigurationInitializer
```

I'm sure it is an issue of class loaders. And here I guess you place `spring-integration-http` to the XD module classpath, where it should be placed to the parent `xd\lib` classpath.

Although I don't see reason to worry about `spring-integration-http` there because the raw `spring-web` should be enough for you, since you use only `RestTemplate` from your code.

The recipe is: don't place anything to the module classpath until you rally see that XD doesn't accept your module with the common classpath.